# SignalR and MVC5: How to call Controller action method from hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm sorry, I guess this is a very trivial question, since I'm very new to SignalR and MVC5.

Is it possible to call a controller's action method from within a hub?
I only hear people asking the other way round. I know hub are not classes in the typical way...

If yes, what "using" do I need for that? (Of course, the Action Method is public)

Thanks!

Comment: why would you do that ?

Comment: You should refactor so that any dependency that are inside that action method is abstracted

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you want to achieve? When you interact with your Hub in your controller, you can send messages to all the users that are connected to that particular Hub. I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say you want to do it the other way around. Actions in your controller should really only be invoked through an HTTP request.

Comment: Well the answers here show me, that my way to do what I have to do is stupid. That's good information. So I'd say this question has been "answered". Thank you anyway :)